# OpenSSL 1.0.2/C++: const or define for "Handshake Type: Server Key Exchange (12)"?

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, handshake

does OpenSSL 1.0.2 provide a const or define for "Handshake Type: Server Key Exchange (12)"? Or can I cast the block of data received in the callback for SSL_CTX_set_msg_callback into some structure? Such that I do not have to interpret the bytes myself?

BR, Rene

Comment: Handshake types are defined at https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/8377f26c2e6dadd9a1728805cd895fa94669f2d0/ssl/t1_trce.c for example but why using such an old OpenSSL version? `1.0.2`? From OpenSSL website: "All older versions (including 1.1.0, 1.0.2, 1.0.0 and 0.9.8) are now out of support and should not be used."

Comment: 1.0.2 is a customer requirement (fips for mobile). My customer has support for 1.0.2 via SafeLogic.